# iPhone SSL client certificate not working

Tags: iphone, iis, ssl, certificate, x509

Authenticating user with RSA certificate through iPhone' Safari browser not working with IIS website. I cant get it working. IIS just gives up with "client certificate required" error and safari doesn't provide certificate.

Client:

- iPhone 3G latest firmware
- CA and user certificates deployed (it shows them as unsigned)

Server:

- IIS, windows XP (there are unanswered questions on web regarding iis7 too)
- Require client certificate setting is on

Certificates:

- RSA
- one CA for user and server

Notes:

- SSL without client auth working well.
- i've read Dartmouth, UVa and MIT instructions concerning iPhone configuration - these are for wifi i guess

Problems i cant resolve for now:

- Safari returning encrypted alert 21 during handshake (i suppose this is TLS' decryption_failed error) - WHY?
- Any Certificate Requirements on SSL client authentication for iPhone - WHERE?
- Anybody got it working through SSL reverse proxy, for example - HOW?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround using STunnel reverse proxy.